# Selecting Latest Row From MAX Row of 3rd Table

Tags: mysql

This is a related query to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193329/ordering-a-mysql-result-set-by-a-max-value-of-another-table), but it involves 3 tables instead of 2.

We have 3 tables:

```
People:
personid, name

PeopleEvents:
personid,eventid,eventdate

EventTypes:
eventid,eventname,eventsequence
```

The tables would have data like:

```
People:
1,John
2,Mary
3,Jane
4,Rob

PeopleEvents:
1,100,1/1/2013
2,100,2/2/2013
2,102,2/3/2013
2,104,3/3/2013
3,100,4/4/2013
3,102,4/4/2013
4.100,2/2/2013
4,103,4/4/2013
4,104,3/3/2013

EventTypes:
100,Joined company,10
101,Induction,20
102,Introduction,17
103,Second meeting,25
104,First meeting,15
```

We want to be able to pull out a list of people based on highest EventType sequence, NOT event ID.

Thus the report  would be:

```
John,Joined Company
Mary,Introduction
Jane,Introduction
Rob,Second meeting
```

This to me seems inelegant but appears to work:

```
SELECT p.personid,et.eventname FROM people p 
INNER JOIN peopleevents pe ON p.personid = pe.personid
INNER JOIN eventtypes et ON et.eventid = pe.eventid
WHERE p.personid NOT IN
(SELECT p1.personid FROM people p1 LEFT JOIN peopleevents pe1 ON p1.personid = p.personid
LEFT JOIN eventtypes et1 ON et1.eventid = pe1.eventid
WHERE p1.personid = p.personid AND et1.eventseq > et.eventset) ORDER BY p.name;
```

The way I see it the sub-query is attempting to find a higher sequence than the main query and thus only allowing the main query to return the highest sequenced event.

I will enter the answers provided to see if one of them will provide a tidier solution.

Comment: Obviously, any sensible solution will assume that dates are stored within a DATE data type. That said, the 'uncorrelated subquery' [ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html ] solution provided with the mysql documentation will give you what you want, and probably in a shorter time than any of the other solutions (both documented and undocumented).

Comment: @Strawberry, the date is pretty much irrelevant really. In reality it would appear in the report but it is getting the highest sequence event that is important.

Comment: @blankabout See my edited solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT p.*, et.eventname, et.eventsequence FROM people p
    JOIN PeopleEvents pe
      ON p.personid = pe.personid
    JOIN EventTypes et
      ON et.eventid = pe.eventid
  ORDER BY eventsequence DESC
) t
GROUP BY personid
```

Comment: `select * from [..] group by personid` that is horrible SQL. Any mature database (such as oracle) would not allow this. MySQL will allow this but pick random values from all rows not present in the group by clause. This has nothing to do with what was requested.

Comment: not that oracle has *anything* to do with mysql ;-) - but I agree with the sentiment

Comment: We get quick and correct result. I can say it is not horrible, it even helps to do a simple trick in MySQL, which is impossible in standard SQL. So, all rows from `people` we can consider as unique and no aggregate functions are needed, then GROUP BY selects FIRST record from the `EventTypes` table.

Comment: I substituted column names for the wild cards and this does the trick.

Comment: All of the answers to date did the job, so thanks & points all round. Chose this one as 'the answer' despite having to edit it to get rid of  the wild cards because it was the shortest.

Comment: Short does not make it correct, though. This is exploiting a fault tolerance mechanism of MySQL that is not reliable. But if it works for you, stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you your answer

**Edit** I was struggling with the result I was getting because your example data is wrong in the desired result Mary should be 'First meeting'

**Edit 2** So as you say that the sequence is the third field (I was thinking that was the first one) on the table eventTypes

```
select p.name, e.eventname 
from People p,
     EventTypes e,
(select p.id, max(e.seq) seq
  from People p,
       PeopleEvents pe,
       EventTypes e
 where p.id = pe.pid
   and e.id = pe.eid
 group by p.id) pe
where p.id = pe.id
  and e.seq = pe.seq
```

See it here at new fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1183c/1

Comment: this would not give the desired list, but a list of all people and events with the date they attended each event the last time.

Comment: Thanks for you input but it is the latest event by eventsequence, not date, that is required.

Comment: As I require the event with the maximum sequence number (not eventid) Mary should definitely be reported as having experienced 'Introduction', the events she is recorded as doing are Joined Company = seq 10, Introduction = seq 17, First meeting = seq 15, thus the highest sequence event, the one we are interested in, would be Introduction even tho' the eventid is lower than 'First meeting'.

Comment: @blankabout Well I was confused about the third field. Now it is working. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.name, group_concat(e.eventname)
from People p
join (p1.personid, max(et1.eventsequence)  as eventsequence
      from People p1
      join PeopleEvents pe1 on p1.personid = pe1.personid
      join EventTypes et1 on pe1.eventid = et1.eventid
      ) sub
  on p.personid = sub.personid
join PeopleEvents pe on p.personid = pe.personid 
join EventTypes et on pe.eventid = et.eventid
  and et.eventsequence = sub.eventsequence
group by p.personid
```

This will give you a list of all people with their event(s) with the highest eventsequence. If they attended two event with the same sequence and they are the last, both events will show up. Even if there is more than 1 person with the same name, each person will get a separate row.

**Update** to make Strawberry happy. The rsult is the same, btw:

```
SELECT p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(e.eventname)
FROM People p
JOIN PeopleEvents pe ON p.personid = pe.personid 
JOIN EventTypes et ON pe.eventid = et.eventid
WHERE et.eventsequence = (SELECT MAX(et1.eventsequence)
                          FROM PeopleEvents pe1
                          JOIN EventTypes et1 ON pe1.eventid = et1.eventid
                          WHERE pe1.personid = p.personid)
GROUP BY p.personid
```

Comment: @drunken_monkey This seems to do the trick, what does the GROUP_CONCAT bring to the party apart from concatenating the event names, which isn't something particularly desired?

Comment: i added it for safety reasons. If you had a user with two different events but the same eventsequence, then the group_concat would give you a string with "event1,event2". Without the group_concat, mysql would choose a randomly between the two which is not deterministic, hence wrong. If you make sure that no two events can have the same eventsequence (e.g. with a unique key on the column), then you can ditch the group concat and jsut select the eventname.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I would do it this way. I've renamed a couple of your columns according to my own naming convention - a habit borne from the great 'pen island' catastrophe.

```
SELECT p.name
     , et.event_name
  FROM people p
  JOIN people_events pe 
    ON p.person_id = pe.person_id 
  JOIN event_types et 
    ON et.event_id = pe.event_id 
  JOIN  
     ( SELECT pe.person_id
            , MAX(et.event_sequence) max_event_sequence
         FROM people_events pe
         JOIN event_types et 
           ON et.event_id = pe.event_id   
        GROUP 
           BY pe.person_id
     ) y
    ON y.person_id = p.person_id
   AND y.max_event_sequence = et.event_sequence;
```